# How to get the column name that contains a list of values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to return the column name that has the strings from a list.

```
import pandas as pd
names = ['Brian', 'John']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"], data=[['abc']*6]*6)
df['D'] = ['Brian', 'John', "Mike", 'Brian', 'John', "Mike"]
print(df)
col_name = ([i for i in df  if df [i].isin([names]).any()])
```

This does not work with a list. Is there any way to pass this the list of names and print the column name that contains those values?

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
df.columns[df.isin(names).any()]
```

Output:

```
Index(['D'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should be modified to:

```
df.columns[[df[i].isin(names).any() for i in df]]
```

Or you can try with:

```
df.columns[df.stack().isin(names).any(level=1)]
```

---

```
Index(['D'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the columns that contain both names (and not just one), this should work:

```
df.loc[:,df.stack().loc[lambda x: x.isin(names)].groupby(level=1).agg(set).eq(set(names))].columns
```